# Trying to keep image contained within another image

Tags: html, css

I am using jQuery to change the size of a image after a click. How can I keep a close button contained within the upper right corner no matter what the size of the image becomes after the click. 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9LDp/1/)

My css

```
#full_image {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: relative;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 9;
}

#full_image img { 
background: url("zoom-on.png") no-repeat;
background-position: 5px 5px;
left: 0px;
width: 339px;
height: 211px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#full_image .full_close{
background: url("zoom-on.png") no-repeat;
top: 10px;     
cursor: pointer;
 height: 29px;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;    
width: 29px;
z-index: 999;
right: 0px;
}
```

my html

```
<div id="full_image"><img src=""/>
<span> <a href="#" class="full_close"></a></span>
</div>
```

The thing is I can keep the image contained within #full_image but I need it contained within #full_image img

Comment: put a complete jsFidlle if you want actual help.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `.. I need it contained within #full_image img` ?

Comment: #full_image img is what actually contains the image #full_image is a container which after some jquery animation becomes larger than the image thus that's why I need the other image contained within #full_image img

Comment: Why do you set `#full_image { width: 5px; height: 5px; }` in your fiddle? In your question, `#full_image` has the same dimensions as the `img`. Is it intentional to use the same image twice?

Comment: updated. I just need figure out a way to keep the .full_close contained within img

Comment: You have asked this question a million times. The answer is create a div and absolute position both images in the top right of that div. You need to change the logic of your click event to work with an auto width, height div. Your approach is in correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```css
#full_image {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; zoom:1; /* IE7 fix */
    z-index:1;
}
#full_image span {
    background:url("zoom-on.png") no-repeat;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
#full_image:hover span {
    display:block;
}
```

and HTML

```html
<div id="full_image">
    <img src="image.jpg" /> <a href="#" class="full_close" title="Close"><span> </span></a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9LDp/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9LDp/2/). Is this is waht you want?

I've created a `DIV` with `full_image` `ID` and set the image as a `background`. 

Then I've added the `close button` into the `DIV` and `position`-ed them both.

So the `close button` will be always at the top-right corner of the `image` despite the `image` size.